# How can I use Hazelcast as caching backend for bazel

Tags: hazelcast, bazel

I understood that hazelcast can be used as backend for bazel cache. If true, how can is set this up ?
I want to set up a bazel cache which is horizontally scalable. Currently we are using bazle remote in an Azure VM and sometimes we face DISC iops or network issues during peak hours.
Any suggestions on scalable bazel cache solution are welcome

Answer (score 0):

I’m not particularly familiar with Bazel, is it built on Java? If so, this sounds like a situation where you would embed a Hazelcast node directly in the Bazel app. In this configuration, when Bazel instances are started, the embedded Hazelcast nodes will find each other, form a cluster, and share data between them automatically.

If it’s not Java, then you would use client/server mode, which means instead of embedding Hazelcast itself, you set up a stand-alone Hazelcast cluster and then embed the client in the app.

Either way, you then have the full Hazelcast API and structures to use from within Bazel. How you connect Bazel to Hazelcast at this point I’m not sure.

Hazelcast also supports JCache, Memcached, Hibernate, has a REST API, etc. so you might be able to use a standard API to plug Hazelcast in.

I took a quick look at Bazel docs but didn’t see anything related to configuring a caching layer, but I may have missed it. Hope this helps and let us know if you make progress, I’d be interested in hearing how this turned out.

Comment: Bazel expects an http(s) url. Part of my question is: How can I set up standalone hazelcast and an http service on top of it ?